# Why my arrow function is not returning p tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions, react-props

Hi i am new to learning react framework and working on a simple app i have now two arrow functions FormSubmitAsset and FormSubmitCash i want both of them to return the value of input when the form is submitted through p tag but its not working kindly help me in this regard

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

console.log("Financial Accounting is running");
class FinancialAccount extends React.Component{


render(){
const title = 'Financial App';
return(
( 
 <div>
<Header title={title}/>
<Assets 
 FormSubmitAsset =  {this.FormSubmitAsset} 
 FormSubmitCash = {this.FormSubmitCash}
  /></div> ))}

  }

   class Assets extends React.Component{
   FormSubmitAsset =(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();   
      const option = e.target.elements.input.value.trim(); 
   console.log(option)
      }

     FormSubmitCash =(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
      const option = e.target.elements.inputCash.value.trim();

    console.log(option)

       } 

  render(){
 return(<div>
    <form onSubmit={this.FormSubmitAsset}>
    <input type ='text' name = 'input'></input>
    <button>Add Asset</button>
    </form>
    <form onSubmit={this.FormSubmitCash} >
    <input type ='number' name ='inputCash'></input>
    <button>Add Cash</button>
    </form>
    </div>)
   }}

  const Header =(props)=>{
 return(<h1>{props.title}</h1>
 )}



    export default FinancialAccount;
```

i want FormSubmitAsset and FormSubmitCash to return value in in paragraph

it tried to do

```
      FormSubmitAsset =(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();   
   const option = e.target.elements.input.value.trim(); 
   return (
        <div>
       <p>{option}</p>
       </div>   )
     }
```

but its not returning anything

as a check i am doing

```
      console.log(option)
```

but its not the ideal way

Comment: It **is** returning that. It just isn't returning it anywhere useful.

Comment: You have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to achieve by returning from the onsubmit function?

Comment: i think you didnt understand my problem thats why you are saying that the value in <p> {option}</p> is not showing to screen

Comment: @Saadi what you return from your event handler will not be rendered. so you could use state in `Assets` component

Comment: There's way too much wrong here to offer a solution... here are the docs on how to properly handle forms in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `const option = e.target.elements.input.value.trim();` which actually return you the element on which the element is bind not the actual input you want.

Actually you can do something like this

```html
render(){ return(
<div>
  <form onSubmit={this.FormSubmitAsset}>
    <input type='text' name='input'></input>
    <button type="submit">Add Asset</button>
  </form>
  <form onSubmit={this.FormSubmitCash}>
    <input type='number' name='inputCash'></input>
    <button type="submit">Add Cash</button>
  </form>
</div>) }} const Header =(props)=>{ return(
<h1>{props.title}</h1>
)} `
```

```js
FormSubmitAsset =(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();   
   const option = document.getElementById("input"); 
   return (
        <div>
       <p>{option.value}</p>
       </div>)
}
```

Comment: I value your effort but now its throwing an error of  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Answer (score 0):

What you return from your event handler will not be rendered i.e

```
// will not be rendered
return (
        <div>
          <p>{option}</p>
        </div>  
     )
```

Instead you can use state in `Assets` component and update the component state with the input field value and conditionally render them.

You can do it in two way. Using `controlled` component or `uncontrolled` component.

[Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html): In controlled component, form data is handled by a React component.

[Uncontrolled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html): In uncontrolled component, form data is handled by the DOM itself.

**Uncontrolled Component**

```
class Assets extends React.Component {    
  // creating property in state 
  //  for each input field
  state = {
    asset: "",
    inputCash: ""
  };

  FormSubmitAsset = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const option = e.target.elements.input.value.trim();
    // updating state with input field value
    this.setState({ asset: option });
  };

  FormSubmitCash = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const option = e.target.elements.inputCash.value.trim();
     // updating state with input field value
    this.setState({ inputCash: option });
  };

  render() {
    const { asset, inputCash } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.FormSubmitAsset}>
          <input type="text" name="input" />
          <button>Add Asset</button>
        </form>
        <form onSubmit={this.FormSubmitCash}>
          <input type="number" name="inputCash"/>
          <button>Add Cash</button>
        </form>
        // if "assest" is not empty 
        // render "assest" 
        {asset && <p> {asset} </p>}
        // "inputCash" is not empty
        // render "inputCash"
        {inputCash && <p> {inputCash} </p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Controlled Component**

```
class Assets extends React.Component {

  // add state 
  state = {
    asset: "",
    inputCash: "",
    finalAsset: "",
    finalInputCash: ""
  };

  formSubmitAsset = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ finalAsset: this.state.asset });
  };

  formSubmitCash = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ finalInputCash: this.state.inputCash });
  };

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          // binding input field value with state property "asset"
          // update state value with event handler "changeHandler"
          <input type="text" name="asset" value={this.state.asset} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
          <button onClick={this.formSubmitAsset}>Add Asset</button>
          <br />
          // binding input field value with state property "inputCash"
          // update state value with event handler "changeHandler"
          <input type="number" name="inputCash" value={this.state.inputCash} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
          <button onClick={this.formSubmitCash}>Add Cash</button>
        </form>
        // if "finalAsset" is not empty 
        // render "finalAsset"
        {this.state.finalAsset && <p> {this.state.finalAsset} </p>}
        // if "finalInputCash" is not empty
        // render "finalInputCash"
        {this.state.finalInputCash && <p> {this.state.finalInputCash} </p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also you don't need to pass props to `Assets` component.

```
class FinancialAccount extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const title = "Financial App";
    return (
      <div>
        <Header title={title} />
        // No need to pass props 
        <Assets />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```